# Toggling a modal that has an index with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a loop of objects that each has it's own settings modal. When you click on the settings button it shows the modal, but I can't click the button again to hide it.

My state looks like the following:

```
this.state = {
  settingModal: -1
}
```

I have a function that shows the settingsModal:

```
  showSettings(index) {
    this.setState({
      settingModal: this.state.settingModal === index ? -1 : index
    })
  }
```

Then inside the objects loop, the onclick is:

```
            <div className="arrow__container" onClick={this.showSettings.bind(this, i)}>
              <div className="arrow" />
            </div>
```

EDIT:

This is the display code:

```
  /**
   * Post display logic
   */
  viewPublishedPages() {

    const objects = this.state.objects;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="ObjectsList">
          {objects.map((val, i) => {
            let dropdown = 'none';
            return (
              <div key={i} className="block">
              <div className="columns">
                <div className="column is-10">
                  <p>PUBLISHED</p>
                  <h2>{val.title}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="column">
                  <div className="settings">
                    <div className="arrow__container" onClick={this.showSettings.bind(this, i)}>
                      <div className="arrow" />
                    </div>
                    {
                      this.state.settingModal === i ?
                         <ClickOutside onClickOutside={::this.hide}>
                          <div className="arrow__dropdown">
                            <Link href={{pathname: '/admin/edit-page', query: {title: val.title}}}>
                              <a className="arrow__dropdown__link">Edit</a>
                            </Link>
                            <button
                              className="arrow__dropdown__delete"
                              onClick={() => this.handleDelete(i)}>Delete</button>
                          </div>
                        </ClickOutside> 
                        : null
                    }

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>


      </div>
    );
  }
```

I'm used to just checking if a modal is active with true & false. I tried adding an if statement inside the function `this.state.settingModal === index` then set the state to `settingModal: -1` else run the regular command. This doesn't seem to work. It only shows the modal, but when I click again nothing happens.

Comment: Please paste more complete code. What is the modal code?

Comment: @Chen-TaiHou oops forgot that part. Added it now

Comment: What is ClickOutside component? Are you sure it triggers `onClickOutside`?

Comment: where do you initialize i variable used in this.state.settingModal === i

Comment: @Chen-TaiHou It allows me to click anywhere on the screen and call a function. I need to be able to click on the arrow to close the modal tho.

Comment: @SajithDilshan That's within the objects loop ```objects.map((val, i) => ```

Comment: So your problem is the modal cannot close or you cannot trigger the modal again? Please paste complete code or it's hard for community to help you.

Comment: @Chen-TaiHou Ok. Just added everything the whole render code